# How to calculate tide times?

Tags: astronomy, tidal-effect

How do I calculate the time of the tides at a given location?

I'm not interested in the amplitude of the tides,  just the times when they occur.

Comment: This answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121830/ explains why the ocean's response to tidal forcing is complex.  There is no simple answer that can be calculated.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot more to it than just astronomy.  For example, the tide times inside Boston Harbor are significantly different from those on the southeast coast of Cape Cod.
It is true that the primary force behind tides is the position of the Moon, but the macro tidal bulges take a long time to propagate around/across oceans, and then the shoreline shape makes a big difference at the end.

Further, the two-a-day tidal pattern in the Atlantic is pretty much symmetric, while the Pacific Coast tides follow a "low-low" and "high-high" pattern. That is, the two low tides are of repeatably different level, and same for the high tides.