# Are the high tides always more unequal when the centre of gravity is within a planet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, planets, tidal-effect

In case of our high tides at both sides of the Earth it seems that they are almost equal. But is there a slight difference because the center of gravity is about 1,700 km below the surface of the Earth? So if this center is just outside the Earth would they be exactly the same?

Comment: The model of "high tides at both sides of the Earth" isn't accurate.  See [Does Earth really have two high-tide bulges on opposite sides?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121830/does-earth-really-have-two-high-tide-bulges-on-opposite-sides)

Comment: Well in that case, I propose to eliminate these particular details and just focus on a simplified model