Would there be tidal differences either side of a wall built through the ocean?
I'm trying to understand tidal forces. Here's a puzzle I've come up with.
Suppose we build a wall which partitions the ocean north-to-south. There is no way for water to pass from one side to the other through it, over it, or around it.
Will the tidal height be the same or different on either side?
Intuitively, I want to say they're different because if the Moon is on one side of the wall, raising the tide would require "sucking" water from the other side, which can't happen. Therefore the tide will be lower on that side to maintain the tidal bulge further out, whereas water on the opposite side will be piling up.
On the other hand, intuitively I want to say they will be the same (perhaps asymptotically) because water can be gained or lost from the north-south directions, and the equilibrium at either side of the wall (at the wall) will be the same.
Which is it?

Ocean heights are different on either end of the Panama Canal.

Here's an answer about tidal patterns on Earth that you may find of interest: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/121858/123208
